# Differences in programming about iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

What are the major differences between developing an application for iPhone and iPad?

Do I need to write additional code?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you can use the same objects and UI controls, but the iPad User Interface Guideline is quite different from the iPhone one.

You will have to write additional code if you plan to build a universal application, in which case you should be able to conditionally change the behaviour of your application depending on which platform it's currently running.

For the iPad platform you can use the new UIPopoverController and UISplitViewControllers, that gives you new ways to interact with the larger screen (more info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html)).

By the way, you will have to build a different set of .xib files, or to handle the existing ones (built for iPhone) so that the can easily adapt to the larger screen. Also, while developing for iPhone you can usually bind your project for a predefined orientation (the portrait), on iPad you should consider the possibility to rotate the view also in landscape orientation.

You should refer to the [official Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/ipad/sdk/) for developing iOS applications, dealing with the UI guidelines and for developing Universal Applications.

Comment: How can my app know wich nib file to load?

Comment: This is a property that you set in your Info.plist file (look for `NSMainNibFile` and `NSMainNibFile~ipad` keys in the guide)

Answer (score 2):

Full details of the differences between iPad and iPhone can be found in the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [iPad Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

iPad programming is basically the same as iPhone programming. The iPad has a larger screen, a few new UI features, and differing performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference in the code for iPhone and iPad.. But Main difference is the nib file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no so much difference only difference is in the view size and some more features like gesture etc are available in iPad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is one major difference among others.

**iPad :** Have the concept of master and details view.

**iPhone :** Doesn't have master and details view concept.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is user interface; iPhone resolution is 320 x 480 whereas iPad has larger resolution 1024 x 768, so you have more space to display things on iPad. In coding there is no difference, a method written for iPhone will run on iPad. But you need precautions in case when you use special hardware like **iPad has no camera**, so if you used camera then you need some checks if camera is not available then your code should not run but display an error message.

Comment: iPad 2 has a camera, while iPad 1 hasn't. iPod touch 4th gen has a camera, iPod touch 1st,2nd,3rd gen haven't. This is not really a difference between iPhone and iPad development, is a hardware-related difference.

Comment: @marzapower, yes you are right, but I made an example, there must be lots of other hardware difference.